# Not able to recognize home directory after upgrading to Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: upgrade, 22.04

Recently I upgraded to Ubuntu 22.04. Prior to upgrading, I used to login with username "sourav" and all my files were kept under the `/home/sourav` directory. After upgrading when I try to login to the system I am unable to find the home directory. I used the command `df - h` and found out that `/dev/sda1` has files of size 81GB . How can I retrieve those files? Also I noticed that none of the web browsers such as Firefox or Chrome are working. System volume is also not appearing on the screen.

Comment: Please show the output of `cat /etc/fstab`

Comment: And also `lsblk -f`

Comment: sourav@sourav-Lenovo-ideapad-320-15IKB:/$ cat /etc/fstab

Comment: # <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=8a96eeb3-32e7-455a-ae81-9c90a09a6174 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
/swapfile                                 none            swap    sw              0       0

Comment: sourav@sourav-Lenovo-ideapad-320-15IKB:/$ lsblk -f

NAME   FSTYPE   FSVER LABEL UUID                                 FSAVAIL FSUSE% MOUNTPOINTS
sda                                                                             
└─sda1 ext4     1.0         8a96eeb3-32e7-455a-ae81-9c90a09a6174  789.9G     9% /var/snap/firefox/common/host-hunspell
                                                                                /
sr0

Comment: There are a lot more being displayed for lsblk -f , but due to space issue cant paste all of them.

Comment: @Sourav rather than pasting information in the comments, which are limited, please [edit] your question to include the additional information. This will make it much easier for you to provide all information in a single place and for others to read 

Comment: Comments are designed for US to ask YOU questions about your Question. You should [Edit] your question to add information. By updating your Question, and using the formatting buttons, you make all the information available to new readers. People shouldn't have to read a long series of comments to get the whole story. AskUbuntu is a Question and Answer site, not a conversation site. If you have an update, [edit] your Question.  If you have a new question, see  [Ask].

Comment: `sudo fdisk -l` and for a very long shot `dpkg -l | grep portal` please [edit] your question to show us.